# Is there a full list of which complication families are supported by each watchOS face?

Tags: watchos, clockkit

It is not immediately obvious which complication families need to be implemented to support a specific watch face.

Also, which complication families can be placed in the same complication slot. For example, it appears the either `CLKComplicationFamily.extraLarge` or `CLKComplicationFamily.graphicExtraLarge` can be used in the same slot on the Extra Large watch face. Yet in my testing only `CLKComplicationFamily.modularSmall` can be used on the `Modular` face, even though it seems like `CLKComplicationFamily.graphicCircular` should fit as well.

**Is there a full list somewhere of which families work on which faces?**

---

I found [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/01/19/watchos-complications-families-templates/) that contains a table with the info I am after, but I'm still wondering if there is any official documentation about this.

Comment: It's bizarre that Apple doesn't document this somewhere

Answer (score 2):

I started a repo on GitHub to document this for myself. Hopefully it will help others.

https://github.com/curiousdustin/watchos-complicated-faces

Comment: Thanks for this Dustin, and for keeping it up to date.

I was searching in order to confirm that there really is no way of creating a complication for that top text location on faces like California & Wayfinder (which by the way supports Graphic Corner & Graphic Circular ) - it is only possible at the moment to use Apple's own e.g "Date" or "Monogram" complications in that position, so I'll log it as feedback I suppose...